# HiveError: The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored in two different boxes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I got an issue when I tried to save the same value in (more than one) different boxes.
Here is the hive's output:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: HiveError: The same instance of 
an HiveObject cannot be stored in two different boxes.
```

I really appreciate, it if someone could tell me, how can I save the same object in multiple boxes
(by default way of doing that)?

Comment: Actually I have solved "my" problem (but not the issue). I just added a value to my model which would take different values in each time (maybe you can think like a random it should make sense).  So the end of the day objects wasn't same :D

Comment: so that means if the two objects of same model and with the same data can't be stored in two boxes

Comment: Getting same error with `HiveError (HiveError: The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored with two different keys ("0" and "1").)
`
Really can't find any solution. Could you please describe your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save the same object in multiple boxes, try to remove the `extends HiveObject` part in the model class. Another option is to create a new object instance. You can create a **`copywith`** method that returns a new object.